How to transition & resize a view from one view controller to another using UIKit & Snapshots?
This question has been asked before here but under different circumstances and older context.
I am trying to seamlessly transition a view from one view controller and have it "jump" into a sheet.
Apple does this in their widget picker for example when you add one of the top widgets.
Based on all the documentation I've read, the most common approach to this is to snapshot the area/view that you are trying to seamlessly transition in the presented view controller (the place where the item is coming from. And then have that snapshot translate across into where it should be in the layout of the presenting view controller.

    func makeAnimatorIfNeeded(
        using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning
    ) -> UIViewPropertyAnimator {
        if let animator = animator {
            return animator
        }

        // Presentation animation
        let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(
            duration: 0.5,
            timingParameters: UISpringTimingParameters(dampingRatio: 1.0)
        )

        guard let fromVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from),
              let toVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to)
        else {
            transitionContext.completeTransition(false)
            return animator
        }

        /// !IMPORTANT: For some weird reason, accessing the views of the view controller
        /// directly, like `fromVC.view` or `toVC.view` will break the sheet transition and gestures.
        /// Instead, use the `view(forKey:)` method of the `transitionContext` to get the views.
        let fromView = transitionContext.view(forKey: .from)
        let toView = transitionContext.view(forKey: .to)

        let containerView = transitionContext.containerView

        let fromFrame = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from).map { transitionContext.finalFrame(for: $0) } ?? containerView.bounds
        let toFrame = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to).map { transitionContext.finalFrame(for: $0) } ?? containerView.bounds

        // Calculate the frame of sourceView relative to fromVC.view to capture the correct snapshot area.
        let snapshotFrameInFromVC = sourceView?.convert(sourceView?.frame ?? .zero, to: fromVC.view) ?? containerView.frame

        // Calculate the frame of sourceView relative to containerView to position the snapshot correctly.
        let snapshotFrameInContainer = sourceView?.convert(sourceView?.frame ?? .zero, to: containerView) ?? containerView.frame

        let snapshot: UIView?

        if isPresenting {
            // Create a snapshot of fromVC.view from the defined area (snapshotFrameInFromVC).
            let originalColor = fromVC.view.backgroundColor
            fromVC.view.backgroundColor = .clear
            snapshot = fromVC.view.resizableSnapshotView(from: snapshotFrameInFromVC,
                                                         afterScreenUpdates: true,
                                                         withCapInsets: .zero)

            fromVC.view.backgroundColor = originalColor

            // Position the snapshot correctly within the snapshot container
            snapshot?.frame = snapshotFrameInContainer

            toView?.frame = toFrame
            toView?.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: containerView.frame.size.height)
            toView?.layoutIfNeeded()

            if let fromView {
                containerView.addSubview(fromView)
            }
            if let toView {
                containerView.addSubview(toView)
                containerView.addSubview(snapshot ?? UIView())
            }

            let toViewCenter = CGPoint(
                x: toVC.view.bounds.midX,
                y: toVC.view.bounds.midY + 55
            )

            let gestureVelocity = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -5000)

            animator.addAnimations {
                Wave.animate(
                    withSpring: self.animatedSpring,
                    mode: .animated,
                    gestureVelocity: gestureVelocity
                ) {
                    snapshot?.animator.frame.size = CGSize(width: 204, height: 204) // Important to animate first
                    snapshot?.animator.center = toViewCenter
                } completion: { finished, retargeted in
                    print("finished: \(finished), retargeted: \(retargeted)")
                }
                toView?.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            }
            
            animator.addCompletion { animatingPosition in
                switch animatingPosition {
                case .end:
                    snapshot?.removeFromSuperview()
                    transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
                default:
                    transitionContext.completeTransition(false)
                }
            }
        } else {
            // Transitioning view is fromView
            if let toView {
                containerView.addSubview(toView)
            }
            if let fromView {
                containerView.addSubview(fromView)
            }

            animator.addAnimations {
                fromView?.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: containerView.frame.size.height)
            }
            
            animator.addCompletion { animatingPosition in
                switch animatingPosition {
                case .end:
                    transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
                default:
                    transitionContext.completeTransition(false)
                }
            }
        }
        
        self.animator = animator
        return animator
    }


I can pull this off seamlessly if the animation involves a simple movement from A to B.
But if I try to resize the snapshot as well, the snapshot becomes pixelated and low quality (I assume this is because the snapshot is literally a small screenshot and I'm stretching it from 56x56 to 204x204).
Is there another way that I'm overlooking to pull this off without a snapshot? Or is there a way I can resize the snapshot without losing quality?
Here is the animator code, it works great without the sizing so this should help future people looking to replicate the same effect anyways.
